# docker postfix - missing logs

Tags: docker, logging, postfix-mta

I created docker container like this:

```
FROM debian

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y syslog-ng syslog-ng-core
RUN apt-get install -y postfix vim \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD /etc/init.d/postfix start && /bin/bash
```

And start it like this:

```
docker run --name testmailsrv -p 25:25 -p 143:143 -p 993:993 -v mailsrvpostfixetc:/etc/postfix -v mailsrvdovecotetc:/etc/dovecot -it mailsrv/mailsrv-0.6:latest
```

My postrix is not working properly, but I can't find any logs to diagnose it. No file /var/log/mail.log, no output from journalclt, nothing interesting from "docker logs" command.
How can I see any log from postfix in docker?

Answer (score 4):

[This image](https://github.com/noteed/docker-postfix/blob/601366d38eaf1b0da38e9dd13c4ad48a85d3f3bb/Dockerfile#L36-L41) suggests:

```
# Use syslog-ng to get Postfix logs (rsyslog uses upstart which does not seem
# to run within Docker).
run apt-get install -q -y syslog-ng

expose 25
cmd ["sh", "-c", "service syslog-ng start ; service postfix start ; tail -F /var/log/mail.log"]
```

That might be easier in order to produce and see those logs (as output of the main thread)

---

Also, [satnhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323316/satnhak) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998673/docker-postfix-missing-logs/46998830?noredirect=1#comment122161123_46998830) (in 2021):

> You probably also need this: [`syslog-ng/syslog-ng` issue 2407](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/2407)

That refers to [syslog-ng/syslog-ng PR 2408](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/pull/2408): "system-source: check if /proc/kmsg can be opened".

Or you would need in your configuration:

```
    source s_local { 
        system(
            exclude-kmsg(yes)
        ); 
        internal(); 
    };
```

satnhak adds:

> adding this to the Dockerfile does the trick:
>
> ```
> RUN sed -i 's/system()/system(exclude-kmsg(yes))/g' \
>     /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
> ```

Comment: But I don't see /var/log/mail.log file in my container?

Comment: @rysic maybe create it first? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165203/7490) (https://serverfault.com/a/738542/783)

Comment: you probably also need this: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/2407

Comment: @satnhak Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: adding this to the Dockerfile does the trick: `RUN sed -i 's/system()/system(exclude-kmsg(yes))/g' /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install rsyslog

   ```
   apt-get install ryslog
   ```
2. Start rsyslog

   ```
   service rsyslog start
   ```
3. Restart postfix

   ```
   service postfix restart
   ```
4. You will find `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: works for me, but should be `apt-get install rsyslog`